# Proof for Supremum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let S = { $x\in\Bbb{Z}: x^2<3$ }. Then S is nonempty and bounded above. Show supS = $1$. Give a rigorous proof.

I have proved supS = $\sqrt 3$ for $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Not sure how to deal with $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: $1^2<3, 2^2>3$, no integer between $1$ and $2$ (and $x \to x^2$ is increasing) should do it.

Comment: $S=\{0, 1 -1\}$ since $n \in \mathbb z, |n| \geq 2$ implies $n^{2} \geq 4 >3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate sets where you can. Here $|x|\geq 2 \implies x^2>3\implies x\not\in S$. Indeed;

$$S=\{-1,0,1\}$$

Which is clearly bounded above by $1$ and has supremum $1$ (If a set has a maximum, that is the supremum)